# Excel - finding unmatched data in order

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I have 2 tabs of data with a unique identifier.  The identifier is not in any particular order.  I need my vlookup / index / match to show me all the identifiers that are not present in tab 2.

Reason: I am working where the systems they used failed a data transfer.  I have to see what data there was compared to what data is currently on the system.  Any data that is missing, i will need to add to the new system.

Example;

```
Tab1 Column A:
123456,
654321,
789456,
456789.

Tab2 Column B:
654321,
123456,
456789.
```

In Tab 3, I want excel to tell me that 789456 is not present in Tab 2.
As you can see in the above example, the unique identifier could be in any order, therefore i cannot put both columns side by side and ask to do a match between the 2 - i need it to look through the whole column.

All the tutorials i have seen assume that column A matches in order of column B

I have 70,000 rows to go through.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To do it with a formula you will want a helper column in the First tab.

In an empty column, I used column B, put the following in the second row:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!B:B,1,FALSE)),MAX($B$1:B1)+1,"")
```

This will create a column of numbers that increment on the ones not found in sheet two.

[image]

At this point you can simply filter on the new column for anything that in non blank and get your list.

If you want to do it with a formula in the Third tab then use this formula that refers to the helper column on the first tab:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(ROW(1:1),Sheet1!B:B,0)),"")
```

Then copy/drag down sufficient to get blanks.

[image]

With 70,000 items I would avoid array formulas as it will slow the calculation down and may even crash excel.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using something like this:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(<value cell>, 'Tab2'!B:B, 1, FALSE), FALSE)<>FALSE
```

Copy all the values from tab 1 column A into tab 3 column A. In tab 3 column B, paste the above formula in every row where there is a value in column A, using referencing the cell from column A and the same row as the value cell. The formula will attempt to look up the value from tab 1 in tab 2. If it is missing, it will generate an error which is caught by the IFERROR function, which will return FALSE instead of letting the error escape. Finally, that FALSE is negated to return TRUE if the value is present in tab 2, and FALSE if the value is missing in tab 2.

From this point you can use a column filter in tab 3 to only see those rows with a TRUE value, that will only show you values that are present in both tab 1 and tab 2.

Answer (score 0):

Soulution for this is `COUNTIF()` the formula would be:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A1)
```

After applying that for all rows, just filter those that have value 0.

Answer (score 0):

This macro will produce a compact list in `Sheet3`:

```
Sub WhatsMissing()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet, s3 As Worksheet
    Dim r1 As Range, N As Long, K As Long, i As Long
    Dim v As Variant

    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set s3 = Sheets("Sheet3")
    Set r2 = s2.Range("B:B")

    K = 1
    N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For i = 1 To N
            v = s1.Cells(i, "A").Value
            If .CountIf(r2, v) = 0 Then
                s3.Cells(K, "A").Value = v
                K = K + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```